# Android Logcat detects camera but camera fails to start, App crashes

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-logcat, android-permissions

I am making a simple app that will open the back camera within the activity and show a live preview. I am working on the code from the Android developers site. The logcat detects my camera but the activity starts and crashes into debug mode and I get no preview. On crashing into debug mode it stops at this line `mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);`

In the manifest file I have the following premissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`

I am testing this on the Sony Xperia Tipo dual phone which has only a back camera. NOTE: I don't want to use intents to open the camera, I just need a live preview within the activity.

I googled a lot before posting.
Any help would be greatly appreciated...
Thanking you

This is what my logcat shows after resuming the suspended thread in the debbuger:

```
10-31 04:47:06.262: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::get_camera_info(int, camera_info*): E
10-31 04:47:06.262: W/CameraService(6916): CameraService::connect: (pid 18358) pre-create object.
10-31 04:47:06.262: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::camera_device_open(const hw_module_t*, const char*, hw_device_t**): E
10-31 04:47:06.262: E/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): HAL_openCameraHardware: camera_count = 1
10-31 04:47:06.262: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): openCameraHardware: call createInstance
10-31 04:47:06.262: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): openCameraHardware:Valid camera ID 0
10-31 04:47:06.262: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): HAL_openCameraHardware: HAL_currentSnapshotMode = 4 HAL_currentCameraMode = 1
10-31 04:47:06.262: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): createInstance: E
10-31 04:47:06.262: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): QualcommCameraHardware constructor E
10-31 04:47:06.272: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): QualcommCameraHardware: recordframes = 7e40b0
10-31 04:47:06.272: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): constructor EX
10-31 04:47:06.272: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startCamera E
10-31 04:47:06.272: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  openCamera : E
10-31 04:47:06.362: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): openCamera : X
10-31 04:47:06.362: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startCamera X
10-31 04:47:06.362: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): initDefaultParameters E
10-31 04:47:06.582: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): Maximum zoom value is 61
10-31 04:47:06.592: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): initDefaultParameters X
10-31 04:47:06.592: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): createInstance: X
10-31 04:47:06.592: W/CameraService(6916): CameraService::connect: (pid 18358) new hardware.
10-31 04:47:06.592: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qvoid android::set_callbacks(camera_device*, void (*)(int32_t, int32_t, int32_t, void*), void (*)(int32_t, const camera_memory_t*, unsigned int, camera_frame_metadata_t*, void*), void (*)(int64_t, int32_t, const camera_memory_t*, unsigned int, void*), camera_memory_t* (*)(int, size_t, unsigned int, void*), void*): E
10-31 04:47:06.592: I/QualcommCamera(6916): cam_nt_cb =0x0,cam_dt_cb=0x0,cam_dt_timestamp_cb=0x0
10-31 04:47:06.602: W/CameraService(6916): Client::Client: (pid 18358) setCallbacks() done.
10-31 04:47:06.602: W/CameraService(6916): Client::Client: (pid 18358) enableMsgType() done.
10-31 04:47:06.602: W/CameraService(6916): Client::Client: (pid 18358) setCameraBusy() done.
10-31 04:47:06.602: W/CameraService(6916): Loading CameraService sounds: /system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg
10-31 04:47:06.702: W/CameraService(6916): Loading CameraService sounds: /system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg
10-31 04:47:06.802: W/CameraService(6916): Client::Client: (pid 18358) loadSound() done.
10-31 04:47:06.802: W/CameraService(6916): CameraService::connect: (pid 18358) new client .
10-31 04:47:12.592: E/CAM_FD(6916): ...config thread select timeout...
10-31 04:47:18.602: E/CAM_FD(6916): ...config thread select timeout...
10-31 04:47:24.612: E/CAM_FD(6916): ...config thread select timeout...
10-31 04:47:30.612: E/CAM_FD(6916): ...config thread select timeout...
10-31 04:47:36.622: E/CAM_FD(6916): ...config thread select timeout...
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::preview_enabled(camera_device*): E
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  : mCameraRunning : 0 mPreviewWindow = 0
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::preview_enabled(camera_device*): E
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  : mCameraRunning : 0 mPreviewWindow = 0
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::set_preview_window(camera_device*, preview_stream_ops*): E window = 0x7fa688
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  setPreviewWindow: E 
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  setPreviewWindow : X 
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::start_preview(camera_device*): E
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startPreview E
10-31 04:47:38.322: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): g_InitDefaultParam = 0.
10-31 04:47:38.342: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): setParameters: X
10-31 04:47:38.342: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  getBuffersAndStartPreview : E 
10-31 04:47:38.372: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): in startPreviewInternal : E
10-31 04:47:38.372: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): bool android::QualcommCameraHardware::initPreview() Got preview dimension as 640 x 480 
10-31 04:47:38.372: I/mm-camera(6916): __func__ Setting camfram_exit to 0
10-31 04:47:38.372: I/mm-camera(6916): Waiting for frame thread to start ! 
10-31 04:47:38.372: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): frame_thread E
10-31 04:47:38.372: I/mm-camera(6916): cam_frame() is ready, call pthread_cond_signal
10-31 04:47:38.382: I/mm-camera(6916): Wait over, frame thread ready !!!! 
10-31 04:47:38.382: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): initPreview X: 1
10-31 04:47:38.382: I/mm-camera(6916): cam_frame() is ready, call pthread_cond_signal done
10-31 04:47:38.382: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): preview_thread E
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startPreviewInternal: mVfeEnabled = 1 
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startPreviewInternal X
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  getBuffersAndStartPreview : X 
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startPreview X
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::start_preview(camera_device*): X
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qvoid android::disable_msg_type(camera_device*, int32_t): E
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qvoid android::disable_msg_type(camera_device*, int32_t): E
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qvoid android::stop_preview(camera_device*): E
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreview: E
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreviewInternal E: 1
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): cancelAutoFocusInternal E
10-31 04:47:38.462: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): cancelAutoFocusInternal X: 0
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreviewInternal: mVfeEnabled = 0 
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreviewInternal: J_mCameraRunning = 0
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreviewInternal: before calling deinitpre mPreviewInitialized = 1
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): deinitPreview E
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): deinitPreview X
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreviewInternal: waiting for old frame thread to complete.
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): runframethread: waiting for preview  thread to complete.
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): preview_thread X
10-31 04:47:38.552: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): initPreview: old preview thread completed.
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreviewInternal: old frame thread completed.
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreviewInternal X: 0
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): stopPreview: X
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::preview_enabled(camera_device*): E
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  : mCameraRunning : 0 mPreviewWindow = 7fa688
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::set_preview_window(camera_device*, preview_stream_ops*): E window = 0x7fa688
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  setPreviewWindow: E 
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  setPreviewWindow : X 
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::start_preview(camera_device*): E
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startPreview E
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): g_InitDefaultParam = 1.
10-31 04:47:38.572: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  getBuffersAndStartPreview : E 
10-31 04:47:38.582: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): frame_thread X
10-31 04:47:38.622: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): in startPreviewInternal : E
10-31 04:47:38.622: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): bool android::QualcommCameraHardware::initPreview() Got preview dimension as 640 x 480 
10-31 04:47:38.622: I/mm-camera(6916): __func__ Setting camfram_exit to 0
10-31 04:47:38.622: I/mm-camera(6916): Waiting for frame thread to start ! 
10-31 04:47:38.632: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): frame_thread E
10-31 04:47:38.632: I/mm-camera(6916): cam_frame() is ready, call pthread_cond_signal
10-31 04:47:38.632: I/mm-camera(6916): Wait over, frame thread ready !!!! 
10-31 04:47:38.632: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): initPreview X: 1
10-31 04:47:38.632: I/mm-camera(6916): cam_frame() is ready, call pthread_cond_signal done
10-31 04:47:38.632: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): preview_thread E
10-31 04:47:38.712: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startPreviewInternal: mVfeEnabled = 1 
10-31 04:47:38.712: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startPreviewInternal X
10-31 04:47:38.712: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916):  getBuffersAndStartPreview : X 
10-31 04:47:38.712: I/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): startPreview X
10-31 04:47:38.712: I/QualcommCamera(6916): Qint android::start_preview(camera_device*): X
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.cameraappdemo;

import android.hardware.Camera; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //checks for back Camera
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "back Camera Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    }    

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);      

}

public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;

    try {
        c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        Log.d("cam", "Camera is not available - in use or does not exist");
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

};

}
```

CameraPreview class using SurfaceView:

```
package com.example.cameraappdemo;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);      
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.

    try {

       mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

       mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Error setting camera preview: ");
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
      // preview surface does not exist
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
      // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("TAG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try clicking the continue button after you get dumped to debug mode so that the actual error will be output to LogCat.

Comment: Are you sure you have 2 cameras? The first error seems to say you don't... ( E/QualcommCameraHardware(6916): HAL_openCameraHardware: camera_count = 1)

Comment: @blahdiblah do you mean to say right click the suspended thread in the debugger and click "resume" ?

Comment: @DigCamara like i said the device only has one camera and that is the back camera.

Comment: @Anafam Yeah, sure. I don't know exactly that the button's called, but that sounds good.

Comment: @blahdiblah ok, just tried what you said and the camera turned on and I can see its working but in debug mode. The logcat is quite long this time.

Comment: @Anafam You could post the (probably short) part of the log file showing the error that caused the drop to the debugger, and we might be able to help.  However, if it works after resuming, it'll probably work in a non-debug build and might be a normal (if obnoxious) part of that device's camera driver.

Comment: I just edited and posted the whole Logcat again, I don't know what could be the problem. Although I tried a similar code like this which worked on my Nexus 7(2012) showing a live camera preview flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to call the reference of the CameraPreview class from on Resume() because the UI takes some time to load so its better calling that object in another thread.

here's what I did:

```
package com.example.cameraappdemo;

import android.hardware.Camera; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //checks for back Camera
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "back Camera Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    }                                           

}

public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;

    try {
        c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        Log.d("cam", "Camera is not available - in use or does not exist");
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

// Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.   
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }       

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

};

}
```

Comment: @blahdiblah Hey Thanks a lot....Resuming that suspended thread in the debug mode helped me figure out where the problem was :)